# この間 pronunciation

Tags: words, usage, pronunciation

Probably a very simple question for those more familiar with Japanese language.
How この間 are usually pronounced? Dictionary gives both このかん and このあいだ, I was wondering which one is most likely to be used in modern language, and is there any significant difference in meaning between pronunciations?

Comment: I've never heard or seen the reading このカン. What dictionary are you working from?

Comment: @virmaior I use zkanji and while marked as not frequently used, このカン is still mentioned.

Comment: There's also このま

Comment: @snailboat I can't cite any specific quotation offhand right this moment, but I've heard it in frustrated exclamations a few times.

Comment: 間 is read ま when it means "a silent pause".  http://search.yahoo.co.jp/search?p=%22%E3%81%93%E3%81%AE%E9%96%93%E3%81%8C%E6%B0%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9A%E3%81%84%22&aq=-1&oq=&ei=UTF-8&x=wrt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are used, but the possible reading depends on the meaning.

**during this time period**: このかん or このあいだ (I think both are OK)

> I have been sitting here for the last two hours.  **During this period**, nobody came.
>   2時間前からここに座っている。この間【あいだ／かん】、ここには誰も来なかった。

**the other day**: このあいだ

> I went to a movie with my family **the other day**.
>   この間【あいだ】、家族と映画に行きました。